# there is a nonnegative nonzero vector $x$ and a positive scalar $\alpha$ such that $Ax \le \alpha x$. Why is $x$ positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n$ be irreducible and nonnegative.

there is a nonnegative nonzero
vector $x$ and a positive scalar $\alpha$ such that $Ax \le \alpha x$.

Why is $x$ positive?

Comment: Nonnegative in the sense that $a_{ij}\geq 0$, correct?

Comment: @Roland - Yes                                                    .

Comment: Does the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem for irreducible matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_matrices) help you?

Comment: @Roland - No dear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$Ax \leq \alpha x$$ we also have

$$(I+A)x \leq (1+\alpha) x$$

By induction you get 
$$(I+A)^n x \leq (1+\alpha)^n x$$

Now use the fact that for some $n$ you have 
$$(I+A)^n >0$$
to show that 
$$(I+A)^n x >0$$